# Set port for outgoing TCP requests in Python?

Tags: python

I would like not only to set a port for the targeted server (TCP) but additionaly for the outgoing signal of a TCP request produced by a Python client application (accessing a Python or other TCP server). Here is what I have:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()

host = '127.0.0.1' # IP address of the server
port = 30000 # Port of the server

s.connect((host, port))
print("Connected")
while(1):
    dataIn = input('Send: ')
    s.send(bytes(dataIn, 'utf-8'))
    dataOut = s.recv(1024)
    print(dataOut)
```

So as you can see, yet, the program only sends some simple strings. That is it.

For one application (as TCP server), I need to set the clients outgoing TCP port to a fix value known by the server. How to do that?

Comment: I would be interested in both, Python and Python 3!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not Python specific but a design issue. A server application should not need any static information about possible clients.

If you need information from the client, one of the first actions after the initial handshake between server and client is to exchange the needed information from a client to a server.

E.g.

1. Server starts listening on Port 3000
2. Client connects to Port 127.0.0.1:3000
3. Client starts listening on Port 4000
4. Client sends port 4000 to the Server and awaits its connection